# Error when passing PHP parameter to SQL Query

Tags: php, sql-server, parameters

I am trying to do delete function using PHP, by require `Connection String` and create the the SQL query, inside it.

Here is my PHP code:

```
function deleteEntry()
{
    require_once('connectionstring/connectionstring.php');
    $conn = SQLServerConnection();

    if( isset( $_POST['Delete'])){
        try {
            $loginID = $_POST['deleteFormID'];

            $query = "UPDATE <table> 
                        SET <column>.active_flag = '0' 
                        WHERE <table>.login_cred_id = ?";
            $parms = $loginID;
            $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, $parms) or die (print_r ( sqlsrv_errors(), true));

        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            echo $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

When I echo $parms it displays the correct ID that should be passed.

I got an error when I was trying to pass PHP parameter to SQL Query even I have set the parameter with the correct ID.

This is the error:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( 
                [0] => IMSSP 
                [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP 
                [1] => -14 
                [code] => -14 
                [2] => An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_query. 
                [message] => An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_query. 
                )
)
```

Comment: Params must be an array so try `$parms = [$loginID];`

Comment: Wow that was the issue... SMH Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parameters, even if there is only one parameter must be passed in an array.

So change this line to make `$parms` an array

```
$parms = [$loginID];
```

Answer (score 0):

Params Should be an array try the following code :

```
function deleteEntry()
{
    require_once('connectionstring/connectionstring.php');
    $conn = SQLServerConnection();

    if( isset( $_POST['Delete'])){
        try {
            $loginID = $_POST['deleteFormID'];

            $query = "UPDATE <table> 
                        SET <column>.active_flag = '0' 
                        WHERE <table>.login_cred_id = ?";
            $parms[] = $loginID;
            $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, $parms) or die (print_r ( sqlsrv_errors(), true));

        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            echo $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```